# Argo Workflow + Performance evaluation + Metrics

Tags: argo-workflows, argo-events

We are evaluating the Argo workflow performance and trying to benchmark the same. For sure the number of components involved in Argo is less than that of Airflow, yet we would like to understand various potential bottlenecks when run at scale.

Following (https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/metrics/) are the workflow-controller-metrics of Argo-workflows (localhost:9090/metrics), looking for explanation of these.

1. **See 5 different queues (cron_wf_queue, pod_queue, wf_cron_queue, workflow_queue, workflow_ttl_queue) listed, what is the significance of each of these queue?**

```
# HELP argo_workflows_queue_adds_count Adds to the queue
# TYPE argo_workflows_queue_adds_count counter

argo_workflows_queue_adds_count{queue_name="cron_wf_queue"} 0
argo_workflows_queue_adds_count{queue_name="pod_queue"} 119
argo_workflows_queue_adds_count{queue_name="wf_cron_queue"} 0
argo_workflows_queue_adds_count{queue_name="workflow_queue"} 91
argo_workflows_queue_adds_count{queue_name="workflow_ttl_queue"} 0
```

**2) What does the below metrics mean? What is "le" here?**

```
# HELP argo_workflows_queue_latency Time objects spend waiting in the queue
# TYPE argo_workflows_queue_latency histogram
argo_workflows_queue_latency_bucket{queue_name="cron_wf_queue",le="1"} 0
argo_workflows_queue_latency_bucket{queue_name="cron_wf_queue",le="5"} 0
argo_workflows_queue_latency_bucket{queue_name="cron_wf_queue",le="20"} 0
```

**3)What are these two sets of queues? One for workflow-controller and another set of queues is for Argo-server? If yes what is each queue doing?**
[image: Argo grafana dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, that the counters

```
argo_workflows_queue_adds_count
```

are "workflow adds". These counters increment on enqueuings to the specific queues. You can use a [delta](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) or [rate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) expression in Prometheus to find how many enqueuings happend in a given time frame.

The second part of your question is a metric of type [histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/). Here you have differnt buckets. `le` means less-or-equal.
For example an object waiting **20** seconds in the `cron_wf_queue` results in an increment in each of the buckets.

Spend le 1 second.

Spend le 5 seconds.

Spend le 20 seconds.

There is also a [Grafana dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13927) available to visualize Argo Workflow metrics.

Comment: I understand the counter part but trying to figure out where each of the queues are used? And also am using Grafana dashboard (updated question with dashboard image)- where in i see two sets of queues. One for workflow-controller and another without any context..